# Filtering Model (not collection) in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I was wondering if it was possible to filter a model like how a collection can be filtered?

I'm doing a search functionality for a sport site and I want to be able filter the search results by type, i.e. football, tennis, basket-ball, swimming, athletic, etc...

Here's my code (check the `filterSearch()` method):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'models/model'],

    function($, Backbone, _, Model){

    var Search = Model.extend({

        urlRoot: '/search',

        defaults: {
            query: ''
        },

        initialize: function(attrs, options) {

            if (typeof options === 'object') {
                this.router = options.router;
            }
        },

        filterSearch: function(type) {
            this.filter(function(data) {
               return data.get(type);
            });
        }

    });

    return Search;
});
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "search": [
            {
                "result": {
                    "query": "Vettel is world champion"
                },
                "type": "Formula 1",
                "id": 1
            },

            {
                "result": {
                    "query": "Romario of Brazil world cup 1994"
                },
                "type": "football",
                "id": 2
            },

            {
                "result": {
                    "query": "federe won again"
                },
                "type": "tennis",
                "id": 3
            }


        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you provide a JSON example of what the results from the search api will look like? It isn't clear exactly what you are going to be filtering.

Comment: @ne8il, thanks for responding. Due to data protection law where I work, I can't show the json I'm working with. But I have included a similar and simpler version that I've made, above though...

Comment: That JSON looks more like a collection than a model. Why don't you have a collection with a `parse` method to unwrap the `search` part of the JSON?

Comment: Agreed. Unless there's more than search in this response, this should be a collection. If the concern is how to get it into a collection, just override parse on the collection to set the search array as the collection data.

Comment: @kinakuta, yes there's more than just the search in the response but I'm only interested in the search. Also, I didn't build backbone code, it was there already, and it'll be too much to refactor with tight deadlines, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason you are using a Model for this case rather than a Backbone Collection? You could easily have a Model for a single search result :

```
var searchResult = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

and a collection to represent the search

```
var Search = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : searchResult,
    urlRoot: '/search',

    filterSearch: function(type) {
       return this.where({'type' : type});
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.search;
    }

});
```

Otherwise just search over the array provided in the model:

...

```
filterSearch: function(type) {
    return _.where(this.get('search'), {'type' : type});
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. The reason for using Model instead of Collection is because I didn't do the code to start with, and it'll be too much to refactor due to tight deadlines, etc... I'll try your solution, hopefully it should be fine.